# What Solr client lib for Python can you recommend and why?

Tags: python, solr, flask

I'am starting to use Python and web-app building with [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and coming from an Java EE background this is a lot of fun. But now I need to communicate with my [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) server and I would like a client lib that is just as plain, simple and fun, so what can you recommend and why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I personally prefer [Sunburnt](https://github.com/tow/sunburnt/). I've started using Python recently as well, and really like the package and how it enables functionality that maps logically on top of Solr.  Just like Python, it does what you need it to do and doesn't get in your way.

Comment: It does not work in python 3.4 though. Neither do solrpy, solrcloudpy, insolr. "scorched" is the python 3 compatible library I found but looks like it still uses older options in solr like /select instead of /query for querying and uses /update/json instead of /update/commit=true. I could not find a good library yet as on October 2015.

Comment: As of spring 2017, I can personally recommend pysolr: https://github.com/django-haystack/pysolr which does support Python 3, as well as it is aware of SolrCloud (leveraging kazoo library to connect to ZooKeeper).

Answer (score -1):

I haven't been able to find a good library that was nice to use and was maintained and actively supported. I started working on a new python client that I plan to keep up to date with new python and Solr releases. I am still rolling in new features, but it is usable and generally stable.

Check it out here: 
https://github.com/moonlitesolutions/SolrClient

Comment: Recommendation requests for off-site resources or tools are off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you answer them, you specifically reinforce the belief that Stack Overflow is a good place to answer those questions. It is not. Please don't answer these questions even if you know a good answer as most answers will be highly opinionated ("I personally like..."). You can open the flag dialogue on the question and see the close reason in full under the **off-topic** category, or in the [help/on-topic]. You should also not even answer in a comment, as the effect is similar to an actual answer.

Comment: The whole point of the question is opinion based, i.e. "What do you recommend?" If you are going to mark down my answer; then why don't you mark down the other one too.

Comment: If you understand that the question is off-topic, why did you answer it? The question was asked and answered 4 years ago, rules were different by then. As you can see the question is now closed. If you seek to discuss further, feel free to [come into chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers).